# Obtaining a specific document ID from sharepoint using web services in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I have an external sharepoint site, where I need to update the metadata of a large set of files. The best way to do this seems to be using the Lists web service, and using the `Lists.UpdateListItems` method. However, this method requires the ID of the document on the server, information I don't have. I do have the filepath/filename of the document.

What is the best way to obtain the doc ID using its name/path?

Comment: how did you plan on identifying which documents to update? what was your intended identifier.

Comment: I have the filepath and name of the documents that need to be updated. So I know that http://MySharepointSite/RootFolder/November/somePDF.pdf needs to be updated for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to go with the web service, you will probably have to go with SPQueries (CAML) to get the items you want.

The Lists.asmx web service (located under http://sitecollection/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx) has a function called [GetListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28office.12%29.aspx) that takes a Query as a parameter.

I don't really know the inner workings of your list, but something like this query should do it :

```
XmlDocument camlDocument = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode queryNode = camlDocument.CreateElement("Query");
queryNode.InnerXml = "<Where>"
+ "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileName' /><Value Type='Text'>{Your Filename Here}</Value></Eq>"
+ "</Where>";

XmlNode viewFieldsNode = camlDocument.CreateElement("ViewFields");
viewFieldsNode.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='ID' />";

XmlNode queryOptionsNode = camlDocument.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

resultNode = _sharepointSite.ListsWS.GetListItems(listName, viewName,
queryNode, viewFieldsNode, rowLimit, queryOptionsNode, webID);
```

The _sharepointSite and ListWS objects are your web serivce objects (they should be generated automatically for you when you add your web reference).

The listName is the name of your list on the site collection

The viewName is the name of the view you want to query on (make sure you have a view that shows all elements if you want to query on everything. I usually rely on hidden views to make sure that users don't change them)

RowLimit is just an int.

You should have no problem finding the ID of the web you are working on with the web service.

The XML that you will get back is not that straight forward and will need special attention. More informat

Note that if you are dealing with nested folders, you will want to add the following code :

```
XmlNode queryOptionsNode = camlDocument.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
queryOptionsNode.InnerXml = "<ViewAttributes Scope=\"Recursive\" />";
```

More information on what I explained [here](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list).

Comment: Fantastic, much appreciated. I ended up using queryOptionsNode.InnerXml = "<Folder>RootFolder/aFolder/anotherFolder</Folder> , giving only documents in a specific folder, to deal with the issue of documents with identical names but differing locations.

Comment: Without the ID of the listItem, it's probably the best way to do it. I imagine that if you have a big set of data, time isn't an issue so doing many queries to loop through your folders probably will be just fine. Glad this solution worked for you!